# Web Scraping and searching on website via python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape [power of 10](https://www.thepowerof10.info/), the website requires a first/last name and a club, i will be getting all this from python . I want to automatically search this website and enter the details, then have the search button pressed so that all the athletes data is display. I would like to get  all the initial details and record them anywhere. I am not bothered how they are display as long as i can get them into python somehow - then eventually sqlite.

Is this possible and how can i achieve this. I do not care about efficiency.

example of searching an athlete: [image: example]

Answer (score 3):

> webscrape power of 10

I investigated their search function using inspector in Firefox browser and found that it is sending GET request with query parameters, e.g. looking for Zharnel Hughes in club Shaftesbury result in following URL

```
https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/athleteslookup.aspx?surname=Hughes&firstname=Zharnel&club=Shaftesbury
```

this does redirect to his page (if found) so you might easily implement getting page as HTML document using requests

```
import requests
search = {"firstname": "Zharnel", "surname": "Hughes", "club": "Shaftesbury"}
r = requests.get("https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/athleteslookup.aspx", params=search)
page = r.text
```

page now contains numerous `<table>`s which you should parse with accordance to your requirements.

> do not care about efficiency.

Then you might entertain using [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) at retrieved `page`, note by default will process *all* `<table>`s it will found and return `list` of `DataFrame`s.

Comment: It seems to open for Zharnel, but if I change it to another athlete it  open me to the page beforehand that requires me to press search. Try changing the URL to Mo Farah   https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/athleteslookup.aspx?surname=Farah&firstname=Mo&club=Newham%20&%20Essex%20Beagles

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can possible handle the situation you're presented with other page than athlete profile with your search:

```py
import sys

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# search = {"firstname": "Zharnel", "surname": "Hughes", "club": "Shaftesbury"}
search = {"firstname": "Mo", "surname": "Farah", "club": "Newham"}

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/athleteslookup.aspx", params=search
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.title

if "Profile" not in title:
    link = soup.select_one("#cphBody_pnlResults a")
    if link:
        link = "https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/" + link["href"]
        print("Reading athlete from", link)
        r = requests.get(link)
    else:
        print("Athlete not found")
        sys.exit(1)

# you're on profile page, read the table with bs4 or with pandas.read_html
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.h2.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Reading athlete from https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/profile.aspx?athleteid=482
Mohamed Farah
```

Comment: using this to get the link, then searching with that link works very well: just need to work on actually accessing the data, currently just writing it to a textfile. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the search parameters
search = {"firstname": "Dexta", "surname": "Thompson", "club": "Blackburn"}

# Make the initial request
r = requests.get("https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/athleteslookup.aspx", params=search)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

title = soup.title

if "Profile" not in title:
    link = soup.select_one("#cphBody_pnlResults a")
    if link:
        link = "https://www.thepowerof10.info/athletes/" + link["href"]
        print("Reading athlete from", link)
        r = requests.get(link) #gets request from the link
    else:
        print("Athlete not found")
        sys.exit(1)

# Parse the profile page with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

dfs = pd.read_html(link) #to allow presentation of the different html tables

print(dfs[2][0])#name table
print(dfs[5])#details about athlete table

table = dfs[8]
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None) #shows entire paragaph of bio instead of limiting characters

print(table)

table_11 = dfs[11] #formats pb table
column_1 = table_11.iloc[:, 0] #get the column to filter rows

condition = ~column_1.str.contains("event|DT|HJ|JT|LJ", case=False)#don't select any rows that contain these as these aren't running
selected_rows = table_11[condition] #all the rows we want that fit condition
selected_columns = selected_rows.iloc[:, :2]#only first two rows are relevent
print(selected_columns)
```

I have got the website link then used pandas to print the specific tables i need